# Generate unique random zip codes with Java Faker

Tags: java, faker

I'm using [Java Faker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker) and would like to generate a sequence of unique random zip codes. Python and Ruby support the `unique` keyword. but I can't figure out how to make this work in Java. Is this feature supported?

Here's the Java code:

```java
// Not guaranteed to be unique
String zipCode = faker.address().zipCode()
```

[Python example](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/fakerclass.html#unique-values):

```py
import faker
fake = faker.Faker()
number = fake.unique.random_int()
```

[Ruby example](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker#ensuring-unique-values):

```rb
# This will return a unique name every time it is called
Faker::Name.unique.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Stream.generate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier) is a great way to generate values. To use it, define a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) lambda that will provide the source values. In this case, zip codes.

```java
var zipCodesStream = Stream.generate(() -> faker.address().zipCode());
```

Use [`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) to make the values unique.

```java
var zipCodesStream = Stream.generate(() -> faker.address().zipCode())
        .distinct();
```

Any number of values can be grabbed using [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-).

```java
var zipCodes = zipCodesStream
    .limit(10_000)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Make sure to use `limit`, or it will never stop collecting. Also be aware that if the source doesn't have enough distinct values then the process will hang!

For an even more powerful implementation, see [Kotlin's Sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html).

---

Full (jdk11) example:

```java
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class scratch {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // use a Thread local random, just in case we're multi-threading
    var random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
    // use the random in the Faker, for consistency
    var faker = Faker.instance(random);

    // generate a Stream - the source values are from Faker
    var zipCodesStream =
        Stream.generate(() -> faker.address().zipCode())
            // make the generated values are distinct
            .distinct();

    var startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // grab 10k values, put them into a list
    var zipCodes = zipCodesStream
        .limit(10_000)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    var elapsedMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis;

    // verify the generated values are distinct
    assert zipCodes.size() == Set.copyOf(zipCodes).size()
        : "Expect zipCodes has no duplicates";

    System.out.println("Generated " + zipCodes.size() + " distinct zip codes in "
        + elapsedMillis + "ms");
  }

}
```

Output:

```
Generated 10000 distinct zip codes in 387ms
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! I prefer using built-in libraries than custom methods. The feature I was working on is complete, but when I have time I'll revisit and outfit it with this solution. If all goes well, I'll change the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the source code (that you linked to), it looks like `unique` is not supported by Java implementation, so you'll need to maintain that yourself.  It's very easy with `java.util.Set<String>`:

```
Set<String> zipCodes = new Set<>();
...
String zipCode;
do {
    zipCode = faker.address().zipCode();
} while (zipCodes.contains(zipCode));
zipCodes.add(zipCode);
...
```

This may be slower than native implementation - or not - but it'll give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This solution works as long as the list of unique zip codes converges fairly quickly (or at all), otherwise I'd also need to implement the equivalent of `UniquenessException` (python) or `RetryLimitExceeded` (ruby), which shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Absolutely.  I don't know how many unique zip codes you need. If it's large enough a set, you may think of a different implementation altogether.

Comment: Good point, I never specified. I need something in the 1k-10k range, so this shouldn't be a problem, since some zip codes generated use ZIP+4 format, resulting in a larger pool, hence fewer collisions.